# Cannot find module twilio when using heroku and meteor

Tags: heroku, meteor, npm, twilio

I cannot figure out how to get the twilio npm module working on a heroku dyno using meteor js.  It works great on localhost, but it crashes on heroku.  This is how I built my heroku app:

```
heroku create meteorherokutwilio --stack cedar --buildpack https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite.git 
heroku config:add ROOT_URL=http://meteorherokutwilio.herokuapp.com/
heroku labs:enable websockets -a meteorherokutwilio
git push heroku master
```

I've added twilio to my meteor project like this:
    mrt add twilio

This is how I'm loading twilio:

```
var client = Npm.require('twilio')("key", "secret");
```

This is the error:

```
 /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:186

 }).run();
    ^
 Error: Cannot find module 'twilio'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
     at require (module.js:380:17)
     at Object.Npm.require (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:88:18)
     at app/meteor-heroku-twilio.js:18:24
     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:159:61
     at Array.forEach (native)
     at Function._.each._.forEach (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:159:5
    Process exited with status 8
    State changed from starting to crashed
```

I've also made a git repo with the minimum amount of code to demonstrate the problem: https://github.com/esromneb/meteor-heroku-twilio/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Npm.require` works only for standard node packages (well, it works for packages it found installed, but you should only rely on it for standard packages, unless you want to manually add packages to your Heroku server and each server you'd like to run in the future).

For all other npm packages, there's `npm` meteorite package.

Add it to your project with `mrt add npm` command.

Then create `packages.json` file with a list of all required packages, for example:

```
{
  "twilio": "1.5.0",
  "oauth":  "0.9.11"
}
```

Afterwards, include your package with `Meteor.require`:

```
var client = Meteor.require('twilio')("key", "secret");
```